# show a span on hover of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, dom-manipulation

I have 2 spans set up in my HTML like this,

```
<span class="job_title">Job Title</span>
<span class="benefits">Benefits description</span>
```

I have hidden `.benefits` using `display:none`

When someone hovers over `.job_title`, I want to replace it with `.benefits`.

This is what I currently have, but it's not working.

```
$('.jobs_available li a').live('hover', function(){
                //alert('hello');
                $(this).closest(".jobs_available li a").next('.jobtitle').hide();
                $(this).next('.benefits').show();
            });
```

Comment: You need to provide more html. Where is your `jobs_available`, li and anchor?

Comment: Logically, this wouldn't work, because when you show `.benefits` (and hide `.job_title`), you won't be hovering `.job_title` anymore, which would change the view back, which would hover `.job_title` again, which would change the view back etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

When hovering `.job_title`, you hide it so you don't hover over it anymore. That's a problem.

This will fix that:

```
<span class="hwrapper">
  <span class="job_title">Job Title</span>
  <span class="benefits">Benefits description</span>
</span>

<style>
.hwrapper .benefits { display: none; }
.hwrapper:hover .benefits { display: inline; }
.hwrapper:hover .job_title { display: inline; }
</style>
```

Without Javascript.

`Element:hover` works in IE7+. (In IE6 only `A`'s have a CSS `:hover` state.)

Comment: I believe IE all the way up to 9 doesn't recognize hover, active, or focus on anything but the rightmost selector.

Comment: Works fine in IE8 (my browser of choice!): http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/SBFCN/show/

Answer (score 0):

Your closest statement is traveling up the dom to look for a .jobs_available li a, which would suggest that your .jobs_available li a lies within another .jobs_available li a.  I think that should just be `$(this).next('.jobtitle').hide()`

it would also help to have more html to see where the .jobs_available li a is in relation to the other elements.